# RegEx: Rewrite URL with exception

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I am trying to change the permalink structure of my **Wordpress** site and setting up proper redirects. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

Old permalink structure:

```
/category/post-name
```

New permalink structure:

```
/postname
```

Redirecting would be fairly simply done by:

```
Source:
/category/(.*)

Destination:
/$1
```

However, the base URL without the post-name must not be rewritten. So if someone access `/category` directly (without specifying a post-name) it should not redirect, because `/category` is a valid page. It should only redirect if something is following `/category`.

Example:

```
https://somesite.com/category -> Don't redirect
https://somesite.com/category/post-123 -> redirect URL to https://somesite.com/post-123
```

Any ideas how I can do this? Note: I am using the Yoast Plugin and its RegEx redirect option.

I am not a coder, so sorry for my gibberish. I hope I am making some sense.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.+` to match at least one character:

```
/category/(.+)
```